# JSON not always responding

Tags: python, json, rss, itunes, itunes-store

Today I began using the `iTunes` `RSS Feed API` in `python` and encountered some errors: when I try to open a ranking using XML (e.g. `https://itunes.apple.com/de/rss/toppaidapplications/limit=200/xml`) it gives me the correct results response -- the results I wanted.

When I try to do this with JSON (e.g. `'https://itunes.apple.com/de/rss/toppaidapplications/limit=200/json'`) I get 'HTTP Error 403: Forbidden'. I know that it worked sometimes in the past (I also used this JSON feed in an iOS App [Obj-C]).

I am using this code:

```
urlStr = 'https://itunes.apple.com/de/rss/toppaidapplications/limit=200/json'
fileHandle = urllib.request.urlopen(urlStr)
```

Is this my fault or is the iTunes JSON feed just bad? Resp. is there any way to fix this or to get the AppStore Charts in a JSON format from somewhere else?

Comment: Does your program run too frequently so it gets blocked by itunes temporarily?

Comment: Actually this happened when I tried this for the first time. How much is the allowed frequency?

Comment: I just tried the JSON URL in my browser and got a JSON answer as expected (I use SeaMonkey so it shows the result right in the browser.)